# iis redirect using variable in URL

Tags: iis

Using an inbound IIS rule can I use variable to redirect to a different URL

```
https://www.cars.com/make/BMW/M3/index.html
https://www.cars.com/make/BMW/index.html#M3
```

would I be able to have it go to

```
https://www.cars.com/BWM.pdf#page=M3
```

IIS Rule

```
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="CarModel">
                    <match url="(http|https):\/\/www.cars.com\/make\/\w+\/[0-9]+\/index.html" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.cars.com/{Make}/{Make}.pdf#page={Model}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Update to post with condition and it will still not redirect

```
                 <rules>
                    <rule name="CarModel">
                        <match url="index.html" />
                       <conditions>
                            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(http|https):\/\/www.cars.com\/make\/\w+\/[0-9]+\/index.html" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.cars.com/{R:3}/{R:3}.pdf#page={R:4}" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
```

only way I was able to get this working was to repeat rule and condition. The # is not working at all;.

```
             <rules>
                <rule name="CarModel">
                    <match url="make\/\w+\/[0-9]+\/index.html" />
                   <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="make\/\w+\/[0-9]+\/index.html" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.cars.com/{R:1}/{R:1}.pdf#page={R:2}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>

             <rules>
                <rule name="CarModelHash">
                    <match url="make\/\w+\/[0-9]+\/index.html#(.*" />
                   <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="make\/\w+\/[0-9]+\/index.html#(.*" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.cars.com/{R:1}/{R:1}.pdf#page={R:2}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
```

Comment: Mistake 1 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: How would I fix it do I move the match url to the conditions